# Binding a ScrollViewer from ViewModel to View

Tags: xaml, mvvm, windows-8, binding, winrt-xaml

I Build a scrollViewer and its elements in my ViewModel, and it's built into a property `FrameworkElement PageElement` I rebuild the `pageElement` every time some event happens, I want to bind the `PageElement` to a real scrollViewer in the View so that whenever I change `pageElement`, it draws itself in it's view.

Comment: Building UI elements in your VM is *not* MVVM.  You should take care of UI concerns in the UI, and program logic in your VM.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I'm trying to build the UI element according to a lot of logic conditions, that's why i have to do it in the VM. the problem is how to send the built FrameWorkElement to the view.

Comment: You dont "have" to do anything in the vm. you can always get the VM from the code behind var vm = myControl.DataContext as MyVMType  ... Task.Factory.StartNew(async() =>{ //your long running logic here });

Comment: @Will, it's a delicate line to say "is not MVVM". I would argue that it can be MVVM with or without binding to UI elements. Having said that, I would continue with that doing so invalidates many of the benefits of MVVM. It's just a strange thing to read ultimatums around a pattern that is so flexible.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT: lol, I'm usually the one berating MVVM orthodoxy (e.g., yes, it isn't heresy for your models/ViewModels to inherit from DependencyObject).  But *constructing UI elements in your ViewModel* is pretty damned crazy.  You're just moving codebehind spaghetti from the UI to a different class.  It's all-around wrong.  OP should be using DataTemplates, but probably doesn't know about them or how to fully use them yet (as you have surmised).

Comment: @Will, I see your point. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you a little armchair advice. I don't know the details of your project but the details in your question make me draw a few conclusions.

First, to have your view model create UI elements is not wrong. But it is really unusual. It sounds like you might be missing the concept of data template or data template selector.

1. Using a data template allows you to have a rich presentation of data that is built as the individual record is generated and rendered in a repeater or in a single content control.
2. Using a data template selector allows you to have various different presentations of data that using code-behind logic will switch between based on data or other criteria.

> Ref on templates: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html

Second, to have your UI be re-generated as the result of an event being raised sounds like a short path to performance problems.

1. Every time you manually create elements and add them to the visual tree, you put your app at risk of binding lag while the layout is re-rendered. Run your app on an ARM and I bet you may already see it. Then again, a simplistic UI may not suffer from this general rule of thumb.
2. Because I do not know the event, I cannot presume it is frequently occurring. However, if it is frequently occurring, then even a simplistic UI will suffer from this.

**Now to answer your question**

Sherif, there is no write-enabled property on a `scrollviewer` that will set the horizontal or vertical offset. The only way to set the offset of a `scrollviewer` is to call `changeview()`.

```
var s = new ScrollViewer();
s.ChangeView(0, 100, 0);
```

You cannot bind to a method, so binding to something like this is a non-starter without some code-behind to read the desired offset and calling the method directly.

Something like this:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    MyViewModel _Vm = new MyViewModel();
    ScrollViewer _S = new ScrollViewer();
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this._Vm.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Offset"))
                _S.ChangeView(0, _Vm.Offset, 0);
        };
    }
}

public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _Offset;
    public int Offset
    {
        get { return _Offset; }
        set
        {
            _Offset = value;
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Offset"));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

But let me caution you. The offset will need to be based on something. And those variables may change based on the window size, the font size, scaling from transforms, and lots of other factors. The code above will work most of the time, but it will possible fail frequently on other devices.

So, what to do? My recommendation is that you code this in your code-behind, monitoring for whatever scenario you feel would require a scroll, and simply programmatically scroll it from bode-behind. Beware, though, programmatically scrolling a scrollviewer could make your UI confusing to the user.

You know your app. You will have to choose.

Best of luck!